# Custom WordPress SQL WC Query for Plugin

Tags: sql, wordpress, woocommerce, plugins

I have a question regarding some SQL queries in WordPress. The object is getting the following information from multiple tables and their columns.

I need: `Ordered Time | Date and Time | Name | Email | Department | Total Orders | Amount`

I've scoped out the following as a visual aid for myself: [image: Text]

`wp_postmeta` contains:

- **Department** as = billing_field_267
- **Email** as = billing_email
- **First Name** = _billing_first_name
- **Last Name** = _billing_last_name

`wp_wc_order_stats` contains:

- **Date and Time** = date_created
- **Ordered Time** = billing_field_739
- **Amount** = ??
- **Total Orders** = ??

The billing fields are meta_keys so I just need their values.

I've tried the following SQL Statement to get what I need:

```
SELECT 
  user.meta_key, user.meta_value
FROM
  wp_postmeta AS user, wp_wc_order_stats as order
WHERE
  user.meta_key='billing_field_267', user.meta_key='billing_email', user.meta_key='_billing_first_name', user.meta_key='_billing_last_name', user.meta_key='billing_field_739'
AND
  order.date_created
```

It doesn't seem to be working as needed some help in the right direct would be apprecaited.

Comment: Every condition in the where clause should be separed by a logic operator instead of coma. `WHERE  user.meta_key='billing_field_267' AND user.meta_key='billing_email'...`

Comment: Are you sure `wp_postmeta` is the right table, The way I see it it should be `wp_usermeta`

Comment: What Does `Total orders` and `Amount` signify?

Answer (score 0):

You have two steps of query you have to work with.

Query one which is the first sub-query is fairly straight forward. The second subquery which build customers' info requires the conversion of **ROWs** into **COLUMNs** in the table which is described in greater detail in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1241178/mysql-rows-to-columns)

Thus, assuming `Total Orders` is number of order(s) in question and `Amount` to be total value of the order(s), the following query should work.

```
SELECT ordInfo.OrdTime as 'order Time',
       ordInfo.DateNTime as 'Date and Time',
       custInfo.Name,
       custInfo.Email,
       custInfo.Department,
       ordInfo.OrdCnt as 'Total orders',
       ordInfo.Amount
FROM
(
    SELECT ord.customer_id as 'customer_id', 
            ord.date_created as 'DateNTime', 
            orderMeta.meta_value as 'OrdTime',
            COUNT(ord.order_id) as 'OrdCnt', 
            SUM(total_sales + tax_total + shipping_total) as  'Amount'
    FROM wp_wc_order_stats ord 
        LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta orderMeta ON ord.order_id = orderMeta.post_id AND orderMeta.meta_key = 'billing_field_739'
    GROUP BY customer_id, date_created, meta_value
)ordInfo LEFT JOIN 
(
    SELECT user_id, 
        COALESCE(MAX(CASE meta_key WHEN 'billing_field_267' THEN meta_value END), ' ') as 'Department',
        COALESCE(MAX(CASE meta_key WHEN 'billing_email' THEN meta_value END), ' ') as 'Email',
        CONCAT(
            COALESCE(MAX(CASE meta_key WHEN '_billing_first_name' THEN meta_value END), ' '), ' ' ,
            COALESCE(MAX(CASE meta_key WHEN '_billing_last_name' THEN meta_value END), ' ')
        ) as 'NAME'
    FROM wp_usermeta
    WHERE meta_key IN ('billing_field_267', 'billing_email', '_billing_first_name', '_billing_last_name')
    GROUP BY user_id
)custInfo
ON ordInfo.customer_id = custInfo.user_id
```